# Pre-filling .sqlite file to add to iOS app, then nothing in .sqlite file but the schema (no data)

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I want to pre-fill a Core Data Database for use in my iOS app.  I am filling the database and I can see the data showing up in my app.  When I don't fill the database in AppDelegate.m I get nothing when I query the database, when I do fill it I get the data I want.  So I assume that the database does have data in it.  I find that filled .sqlite file in my iPhone Simulator->MyApp->Documents.  I drag it to my Desktop, and I am using FireFox's sqlite viewer tool to check for the data in the .sqlite file.  When I do this, I see only the schema, no rows of data besides the metadata and primary key.

When I use the FireFox viewer to view other .sqlite files, I see the actual data, but for this one I don't see it.

Am I somehow deleting the data before I view it in FireFox Tools?

I'm adding the data like this:

```
NSMOSubClass *tempItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];



 tempItem.type = typeF;
 tempItem.internalValue = @(dataUnit.value);
 tempItem.name = @(dataUnit.name);

 [self saveContext:context];
```

I'm saving Context like this:

```
- (BOOL)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{    
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

I'm querying the data like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDel managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

- I made no changes to what Xcode gives when you start an app with CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Context wasn't being saved.  I added the following change:

```
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:storeURL
                                                     options:nil
                                                       error:&error])
```

The difference is the options.  `@{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} }` instead of `nil`.

```
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:storeURL
                                                     options:@{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"} }
                                                       error:&error])
```